# Function inside the svg is not called via javascript in html

Tags: javascript, svg

My HTML looks like below. The mpAddChartValue function is present inside the svg file called mpChart.svg. But when I run the HTML page, I get "Uncaught TypeError: window.mpAddChartValue is not a function" error in Browser console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="Javascript">
  function mpPopulate()
  {

            window.mpAddChartValue()        
   }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="mpPopulate()">
<embed src="mpChart.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="500" height="290" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/svg/viewer/install/"></embed>
</body>
</html>
```

And here goes the SVG contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="mpChart.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
 width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 350" xml:space="preserve">
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
function mpAddChartValue()
{
alert('Test function')
}
]]></script>
```

The mpAddChartValue is just shown as a test function here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have 2 separate documents here. You'd need to get the window of the embed. That's not the same as the html document's window.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Robert for the reply. Could you elaborate or provide me sample code please?

Comment: https://jwatt.org/svg/demos/scripting-across-embed.html